# Get threadId of explorer.exe or get threadId by processName

Tags: winapi, explorer, hwnd

I'm trying to get the threadId of explorer.exe. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. I've looked into win32 apis for functions of appropriate names, but I haven't quite found what I'm looking for.

I know there is a win32 api for `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, but this requires a window handle. If there are no explorer.exe windows open, then how can I get a window handle to explorer? I've thought about using GetDesktopWindow(), but I'm not sure if that gets a handle to a window created by explorer or not. Am I going about getting the threadId of explorer.exe the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: "***the*** *threadId of explorer.exe*" What makes you think explorer would have one single thread?

Comment: Nothing, but I'm assuming it has a main thread, and that that thread has an Id.

Comment: Additionally this question is related to another one of mine with regards to SetWindowsHookExA. I was told you can use this to inject code into another process. But this function requires a threadId to inject into. So I guess I'm looking for a way to call SetWindowsHookExA on explorer.exe and have my HookProc called.

Comment: That's one way to inject code remotely, though not the only way, and possibly not the best way, depending on what your ultimate goals are. That said, API hooking is way too broad a topic to try and piece it all together from SO tidbits.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Will consult more comprehensive guides out there. Thanks again.

Comment: `SetWindowsHookEx()` does not *require* a thread ID, you *can* set it to 0 to hook all threads globally. You would specify a thread ID only if you really have and need one. As for finding a thread ID, you can use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` and `Thread32First()`/`Thread32Next()` for that, if you know the process ID you want to hook. See [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes) and [Traversing the Thread List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-thread-list).

Comment: *but I'm assuming it has a main thread* - wrong. no any *main thread*. and what concrete  window events you want hook ? depend from this need select thread